# Debugging Chat App

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, firebase

I have made this simple chat app with the last message using Firebase but I keep running into this error and cannot seem to get past it. I have checked many things like the @IBOutlets but I cant seem to solve the problem. Can anyone help me fix "Fatal Error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional". The problem, is I cannot seem to find any optionals to start out with, for everything is just its regular data type or has been downcast like the @IBOutlets. Below is my code for one of the view controllers: the one that is causing the app to crash . Any help would be great or advice of what direction to head. Thank you!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class ViewTwo : UIViewController {

    var ref: Firebase!

    var REF: Firebase!

    @IBOutlet weak var readMsg: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var msg: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func sendMsg(sender: AnyObject) {

        nameField.resignFirstResponder()

        if nameField.text == "ETHAN" {

            ref = Firebase(url: "my-app/Person1Msg")

            ref.setValue("\(msg.text)")

            REF = ref

        } else if nameField.text == "CHASE" {

            ref = Firebase(url: "my-app/Person2Msg")

            ref.setValue("\(msg.text)")

            REF = ref

        } else {

            msg.placeholder = "Please enter name ALL CAPS"

        }

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        REF.observeEventType(.Value) { (snap: FDataSnapshot!) in

            self.readMsg.text = snap.value as? String

        }

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }

}
```

Here is the code inside of my other and only other view controller, but no errors are found:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

    var accepted: Bool = false

    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func submit(sender: AnyObject) {

        nameField.resignFirstResponder()

        if nameField.text == "CHASE" || nameField.text == "ETHAN" {

            accepted = true

        } else {

            nameField.placeholder = "Please enter correct name ALL CAPS"

        }

    }

    @IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {

        nameField.resignFirstResponder()

        if accepted == true {

            let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            let nextViewController : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewTwo") as UIViewController

            self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {



        }

    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        accepted = false

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting an exception breakpoint to see where the exception occurs

Comment: Yes. It is this line of code here : '@IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!'

Comment: So it finds nil somewhere when I call on 'nameField' later. I just cannot find where. Thanks.

Comment: So that outlet isn't set. How are you creating the view controller?  Do you ever create an instance without using the storyboard?

Comment: I do not quite know what you mean "isn't set" but if i understand you correctly, yes. In my other view controller, which i will add, I switch to that view controller. I will post the code. That is my only 0other view controller.

Comment: By isn't set, I mean it is nil. Since it is an implicitly unwrapped optional this gives your exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111949/discussion-between-eqoxx123-and-paulw11).

Comment: I think the issue here is that you are calling some function of viewtwo controller when its view is not appearing so the reason for that is if you can't see the controller view than ios sets its view outlets to nil.So accessing their value will give you a crash

Comment: Thank you. Are you referring to when I call on 'override func viewDidAppear' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ViewTwo class, in the viewDidAppear func, there's a REF that has not been totally defined:

```
REF.observeEventType(.Value)
```

and at that point, REF is only defined as REF: Firebase!.

So when the view appears, it will try to call observeEvent for REF that has no ref.

REF is not completely defined until the sendMsg func is called.

Also, you may want to add some error checking in your readMsg assignment:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    REF.observeEventType(.Value) { (snap: FDataSnapshot!) in

        if let msg = snapshot.value as? String {
           self.readMsg.text = msg
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code,`var ref: Firebase!`, ref needs a value. However, in your conditional statements, it is possible for red to have no value. In your final else statement of viewDidLoad, Xcode fatally finds ref to be nil. Try assigning `var ref = Firebase(url:"https://yourappurl.firebaseio.com")` before your conditionals.

Comment: @EQOxx123 This is not a correct answer. Setting ref to what is mentioned in this answer will, as soon as the view loads, read the entire contents of everything in your Firebase; all nodes, children etc and that could be a huge amount of data. Then it will  take that potentially gigantic dataset and downcast it a string, which will crash at some point. There's a lot more to the issue in your question than this answer addresses.